# Show that $\mathbb{E}(X) = \int^\infty_0 \mathbb{P}(X\geq x) dx$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am learning probability theory and I have trouble going from $\int_\Omega X d \mathbb{P}$ to anything with the Lebesgue measure. How can I show that $\mathbb{E}(X) = \int^\infty_0 \mathbb{P}(X\geq x)$ dx with $X$ being a random variable? This must be a duplicate since the equality is very famous but I cannot find it on internet. (I only find it for discrete and continuous case)
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, using the layer cake representation and Fubini's theorem, the proof follows from
$$\mathbb{E}(X)=\int_\Omega \int^\infty_0 1_{X\geq x} dx d\mathbb{P}$$
Then use Fubini (X has to be non negative)